# Why my program is printing the default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a header file that contains the following

```
class newpoint
{

public:
    newpoint();

    newpoint(int num1, int num2);

    double average(int num11, int num22);
};
```

and a.cpp file with the newpoint.h

```
#include "newpoint.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

newpoint::newpoint()
{
    cout << "This is the default constructor talking " << endl;
}

newpoint::newpoint(int number1, int number2){

    int sum = number1 + number2;
    cout << sum << endl;
}

double newpoint::average(int number11, int number12){
    double avg = (number11 + number12) / 2;
    return avg;
    cout << "the average is" << avg << endl;
}
```

and a sourse file that has the .h file as a header and computes the
functions from the newpoint.cpp file by calling them as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include "newpoint.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num4, num5;
    newpoint dag;

    //newpoint dag2(2,3);

    //cout << "enter a number " << endl;
    //cin >> num4;
    //cin >> num5;

    newpoint ave;
    ave.average(2,5);

    return 0;
}
```

why my program is printing the default constructor instead of the
average function?

Comment: What do you think `newpoint dag;` does?

Comment: The constructor runs when the object is created, and you return from the function before displaying the value.

Comment: i know it prints the default contractor, but what about the dag.average?

Comment: Note that the `return` statement causes the function to exit *immediately*. If you have statements after `return` they will never run.

Comment: Some compilers gives a warning, if you place a statement after the return statement. It is called "Unreachable code".

Comment: even after i fixed that, am not getting the average, it is doing the constructor with the two arguments.

Answer (score 2):

> why my program is printing the default contractor instead of the average function?

1. `newpoint dag;` and `newpoint ave;` will call the default constructor of `newpoint`.
2. You write `return` before `cout` in `newpoint::average()`. So nothing will be printed out from `newpoint::average`.

Answer (score 1):

Printing in default constractor is executed because you created objects using default constractor.

Printing in `newpoint::average()` isn't executed because you wrote `return avg;` before the printing statement.

Answer (score 1):

Both `newpoint dag;` and `newpoint ave;` will invoke the default constructor.

If you want your two-argument constructor to be used then write, for example, `newpoint dag(1, 2);`

`ave.average(2,5);` **does** call `average`, but you `return` from that function before the `cout` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
double newpoint::average(int number11, int number12){
    double avg = (number11 + number12) / 2;
    return avg;
    cout << "the average is" << avg << endl;
}
```

you return before your cout statement so you never see that happening. The default constructor will run since you have the line

```
newpoint dag;
```

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor is by definition supposed to be called when you construct an object without any external parameters passed to it.  You can do this in many different ways.  For example

1. `newpoint point1`
2. `newpoint* newpoint_ptr = new newpoint;`
3. `newpoint point1{};`

Basically the constructor is called whenever you instantiate an object of class `newpoint`.  `ave.average()` will only be called when you explicitly call it.